# How to set border-right: none in a label for the last child?

Tags: angularjs, html, css, sass

I have a `label` which return different names (many) in one of my divs, here is how it looks in html view.

```
<div class="customerDisplayFlex">
      <div class="" *ngFor="let cust of customers">
     <label class="dataLabel">
          <input type="radio"
                  name="user-radio"
                  [value]="customer"
                  [ngModel]="currentCustomerContext"
                  (click)="onCustomerContextchange(customer)"
                  class="dataLabel__input" />

          <span class="customer__label">{{customer.firstName | titleCase}} {{ customer.lastName | titleCase}}</span>
        </label>
</div>
</div>
```

here is css of the view

```
.dataLabel{
color: green;
border-right: 2px solid grey;
}
.dataLabel:last-child{
border-right: none;
}
```

I even tried to use sass:

```
.dataLabel{
    color: green;
    border-right: 2px solid grey;
&:last-child{
border-right: none;
}
}
```

in a strange way this does not work what am I doing wrong here? can some one please help? thanks

Comment: We actually need to see a little more HTML, I think 2 levels of wrappers should be enough. And please, show some more `label`s as well

Answer (score 1):

You don't want `:last-child`, you want `:last-of-type`:

```css
.dataLabel {
  color: green;
  border-right: 2px solid grey;
}

.dataLabel:last-of-type {
  border-right: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="customerDisplayFlex">
  <div class="" *ngFor="let cust of customers">
    <label class="dataLabel">Label 1</label>
    <label class="dataLabel">Label 2</label>
    <label class="dataLabel">Label 3</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

⋅
⋅
⋅

Then, you can even enhance the code using the `:not` selector, like this:

```css
.dataLabel {
  color: green;
}

.dataLabel:not(:last-of-type) {
  border-right: 2px solid grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="customerDisplayFlex">
  <div class="" *ngFor="let cust of customers">
    <label class="dataLabel">Label 1</label>
    <label class="dataLabel">Label 2</label>
    <label class="dataLabel">Label 3</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Please read carefully my question :( meaning the solution you provided i have already said also does not work :( here it removes all right border we just want the last one on the right side of our label (names)

Comment: @HotZellah Sorry, but I didn't read that you already tried that, in your question. Anyway, do you have other elements after your labels, as siblings?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
.dataLabel span:last-child{
border-right: none;
}
```

Comment: The border is on `.dataLabel`, not on its child span (see CSS in question)

Answer (score 0):

Is it really the last child in its container? (not only the last label?). (Usually there would follow an `input` tag or similar)

If it's the last `label` tag, you can use `:last-of-type` instead of `:last-child`

---

ADDITION after comments and after more code has been added to the question:

If all `.customerDisplayFlex` are in still another container which contains nothing else afterwards, this should work:

```
.customerDisplayFlex:last-child label { border-right: none; }
```

Comment: its a last label ,

Comment: :last type remove the right border for all label :( confused :(

Comment: that sounds like each label-and-input pair is in a separate container. You should post more HTML code, but in general you would then use `div.label_and_input_container:last-child label { border-right: none; }`, i.e. apply last-child to the container (which again requires another container around those containers where the last label really is in the last child container)

Comment: we need to see the code *outside*  the labels its container/s! (That's where the last-child or similar would apply)

Comment: We still would need to see the structure outside `.customerDisplayFlex`, but i added something to my answer now which could help